# Load property from QML-file in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5.3

I'm building a plugin-system for my QML+C++ application. The plugins are QML-files. 
A qml-file could look like this:

Item {
title: "Sexy Plugin"
version: "1.0"
}

How can I read title and version within C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest wold be, to write a QuickItem in C++. Even when its just a small component, that just holds title and version. Then it is easily accessible within C++ and its the cleanest way, to decouple view and logic.Then you can just define properties with the well-known Q_PROPERTY Macro.

If you actually want to use only Qml-written components and don't want to write anything in C++, there is a solution mentioned at this page: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html

Quoting the relevant part from "Accessing Members of a QML Object Type from C++":

```
QQmlEngine engine;
QQmlComponent component(&engine, "MyItem.qml");
QObject *object = component.create();

qDebug() << "Property value:" << QQmlProperty::read(object, "someNumber").toInt();
QQmlProperty::write(object, "someNumber", 5000);

qDebug() << "Property value:" << object->property("someNumber").toInt();
object->setProperty("someNumber", 100);
```

So QQmlProperty might help you.

As I don't know, what your goal is, I won't recommend anything. Anyway in my opinion, the first way of just writing the Item in C++ is in many cases much cleaner then trying to get the properties from Qml.

Comment: when using "component.create()", does it create a new instance? How about I have two C++ files, both files want to access the already created QObject. How to implement that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Every QML item inherits `QObject` directly or indirectly, so you can use the meta system to read and write properties "dynamically".

```
QVariant QObject::property(const char * name) const
```

> Returns the value of the object's name property.     If no such
>   property exists, the returned variant is invalid.

If the item happens to be the root item, you can use `QQuickItem * QQuickView::rootObject() const` to get it, if not, you will have to set the `objectName : QString` property, avaiable for every `QObject` derived object and call `findChild<QObject*>("name")` from the root object.